# I am getting an error "warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

```
struct student {
    char name[30];
    char rollNumber[20];
    char class[2];
};

void test(int length){
    struct student* tempStudent = (struct student*)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(struct student));
    *tempStudent[0].name = "Hello";
    printf("%s", *tempStudent[0].name);

}

void main(){
    test(1);
}
```

When I try to run the above code, I get a warning "warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast" and the output as "(null)". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You try to assign a pointer to a single character. That does no work. Also assigning a pointer to an array is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

`*tempStudent[0].name` is exactly equal to `tempStudent[0].name[0]`. I.e. it's a single `char` element.

You need to *copy* the string into the array `name`:

```
strcpy(tempStudent[0].name, "Hello");
```

And also use the array itself when printing it:

```
printf("%s\n", tempStudent[0].name);
```